# How to show values for custom property during design-time?

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, user-controls, design-time

I am new to WPF C#, I am trying to create a User Control with custom properties. I have a property with the name Planet.

And this property can take values as Mercury, Venus, Earth and Mars.

During the design time, when I include this control in my application, and type the property name, I want Visual Studio to prompt this 4 values. Like it does when we use the Alignment property for some control and it shows Left, Right, Center..

Can anyone advice me on how to do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You need an enumeration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Depedency property of type Enum. Refer below code.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public Planets Planet
    {
        get { return (Planets)GetValue(PlanetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PlanetProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty PlanetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Planet", typeof(Planets), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(Planets.Mercury));


}

public enum Planets
{ 
    Mercury, 
    Venus, 
    Earth,
    Mars

}
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you very much. Can you also provide me some good references, where I can learn some more stuff like this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you will need:

```
public class Planet
{
    public string mars{ get; set; }

    public string earth{ get; set; }

    public string Jup{ get; set; }

    public string pluto{ get; set; }
}
```